# Query events for the current week / day

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am tying to use the query function in a Google spreadsheet to extract only the current weeks events.

Column B is a date like '8/19/2014' with the column formatted as a date.

To start off with I am trying to just get the current days events I am not sure why neither of the below statements are working.

```
=query(A:C,"Select A,B WHERE B = CURDATE()")
```

or

```
=query(A:C,"Select A,B WHERE B = TODAY()")
```

Again my ultimate goal is to take this a step further and show only the events for the current week.

Comment: your question is not about Google-Apps-Script but rather "spreadsheets" or Google docs no ?

Comment: Sorry wrong tag.   I could also do it with app script, I just thought it might be faster (live time) using the query formula rather than on a timed trigger.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the formula for extracting the current day:

```
=query(A:C,"Select A,B WHERE day(B) = day(now())")
```

Now I just need to figure out how to make it show the current week.

Comment: If you're looking for the week number of the year, there's a built-in spreadsheet function [`=WEEKNUM(...)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949) only available in the new Google Sheets.

If you're looking for to format the date in a generic way, see the [`=TEXT(...,...)` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)